# How to return all the elements of an Array with space between them?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

I am creating a constructor function with some properties and methods. The properties are arrays. 
In those methods, I want to return a phrase with the array elements. 
By default, the elements of the array are presented without spaces between them. Then I created a for loop inside the method to return each element with space between itself and the comma.
It turns out that when I go to the console and call the instance created later with the method, it shows only the first element of the array. 
Can someone explain to me what I did wrong and what I have to do? Thanks
This is my code:

```
function People(first, last, age, gender, interest, caracteristic ){
            this.name={
                first:first,
                last:last
            };

            this.age = age;
            this.gender = gender;
            this.interest = interest;
            this.caracteristic = caracteristic;

            this.bio = function() {
                return `${this.name.first} ${this.name.last} is ${this.age}.Is ${this.gender} and likes ${this.interest}`
            }

            this.greeting = function(){
                return ` Hi! I'm ${this.name.first}.`
            }

            this.personality = function(){
                *// here I try to find a way to show all the caracteristic with some space between*
                for(var i = 0 ; i <= caracteristic.length ; i++){
                    let caracteristica = caracteristic[i] + ' ,'
                    return caracteristica
                }               
                 return ` ${this.name.first} is ${caracteristica}`
            }

        }

        let people1 = new People('Sandra',
                                 'Stward', 
                                 47, 
                                 'female',
                                ['arts', 'cinema', 'poetry', 'photography', 'arts and crafts', 'painting', 'drawing', 'creative art'],
                                 ['kind', 'clever', 'sweet', 'empathic', 'emotive', 'hight sensitive person']
                                 )

    </script>
```

Comment: Don't return in a for loop. It will always return the first item. Consider using `join` instead?

Comment: really? can you explain why is that? because if I write index [i] , would not supose to show them all? thank you for your suggestion!

Comment: Why would it run them all? It will enter the for loop see the return and then leave the function before the next loop runs.

Comment: for loop `i <= caracteristic.length` should be `i < caracteristic.length` also `return caracteristica` should be outside of for loop or just remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array.join(' ')` method. Or maybe `Array.reduce` using a string as accumulator, and at each iteration concat the current with the accumulated string.

Answer (score 3):

A return in a `for` loop will soon end the loop.

But to create a space-seperated string is better done with a join.

```
    this.personality = function() {
          return this.name.first + ' is ' + this.caracteristic.join(' ');
    }
```

That said, instead of a function, you could also use a [Class](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_classes.asp) for this.

**Example snippet:**

```js
class People {
     constructor (first, last, age, gender, interest, caracteristic) {
        this.name={
            first: first,
            last: last
        };
        this.age = age;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.interest = interest;
        this.caracteristic = caracteristic;
     }
   
     bio = () => `${this.name.first} ${this.name.last} is ${this.age}.Is ${this.gender} and likes ${this.interest}`;
     greeting = () => `Hi! I'm ${this.name.first}.`;       
     personality = () => `${this.name.first} is ${this.caracteristic.join(' ')}`; 

}

let people1 = new People(
  'Sandra', 'Stward', 47, 'female',
  ['arts', 'cinema', 'poetry', 'photography', 'arts and crafts', 'painting', 'drawing', 'creative art'],
  ['kind', 'clever', 'sweet', 'empathic', 'emotive', 'hight9 sensitive person']
 );
 
console.log(people1.name)
console.log(people1.bio())
console.log(people1.greeting())
console.log(people1.personality())
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the use of [Array join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

```
console.log(['kind', 'clever', 'sweet', 'empathic', 'emotive', 'hight sensitive person'].join(", "))
```

returns

> "kind, clever, sweet, empathic, emotive, hight sensitive person"